# How to launch a readonly "copy" of a VB Windows Form application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm developping a simple application in Visual Studio in VB.NET language. I say simple because it doesn't need any install, it's a standalone exec file. This programm is stored into a network location to make it available to all employees of my company, but I'm working regularly on it, and the problem is that if anyone is using this app (launched from network), I can't replace file because it is currently used.

Is there any way in VB to launch a Windows Form application with its .exe and make this file still available for any modification?

Comment: AFAIK you can rename the exe even while it's in use, and then add your new exe, although you cannot overwrite while it's in use.

Comment: Have you considered making the application a Click Once deployment?  You can then post the installer on the network drive instead of the app itself.  Then running the installer will install a local copy of the app into the user's AppData folder within My Documents.  

The other added benefit of this is you can then publish updates to the installer and push updates to the users automatically.

Comment: @Jaxi OK i tried it's working, but it's not a good final solution because I have to rename old file, then copy new file and my collegues will have two exec files, and they are... basics users you know...

Comment: @R.McMillan I have to study this option, I tried but it makes a lot of useless files into destination folder, that's why I'm trying to find a solution with VB code or Project properties

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem like this:

- each user has it's own copy of exe
- when the program is launched (or in a timer loop) compare network file modified date (or version number or some other flag) with local copy
- if network file is newer, notify user that there's a new version available to download
- (conditionally) start a small helper program which copies new files to local folder, close current exe and launch it from downloader (helper) again after it copies all new files

Comment: "each user has it's own copy of exe" Maybe something like when starting app "If Not Application.CurrentPath = %userdata% Then Copy Exe file to %userdata%, launch application from %userdata% and close this application". Is there any "proper" way to do this ? At this moment, because of Windows 10 package installation for big compagnies it's hard to add an exe file to all computers and all profiles when starting

Comment: No, I forgot to mention, the first time you have to manually copy the whole program to local folder. Or maybe your way will work. I'm not saying this approach is the best or proper, sometimes you have to do things a bit around the corners.... don't know about win 10 perks, never had such problems with it.. maybe look into "click once" option as someone suggested. Might be easier in the end.